# Less detailed drawing in javascript

Tags: javascript, drawing, html5-canvas

I have this canvas that you can draw on, but since I'm going to use a physics library on the whole thing at some point, I'd like the drawing to be a bit less detailed.
I was thinking about something along the lines of reading the mouse position at a certain interval and then just drawing a straight line to the new mouse position. I've somehow tried this with setInterval and setTimeout, but it never does anything close to what I'd like to see. Does anyone have any suggestions how I could do this?

Thank you!

Comment: Try the other way around: accept all input, and simplify it afterwards. Look for "vector smoothing" techniques.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is a javascript implementation of Douglas-Peucker path simplifying.**

http://mourner.github.io/simplify-js/

*(See full code for simplify.js below.)*

You might also consider using curves instead of lines to reduce points (path smoothing)

Smoothing paths is an often considered task:

Douglas Alan Schepers (from w3c):

http://schepers.cc/getting-to-the-point

The Spiro library (as used in Inkscape, etc):

http://www.levien.com/spiro/

Ken Fyrstenberg Nilsen (frequent contributor at SO):

http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/562175/Draw-Smooth-Lines-on-HTML5-Canvas

Paper.js has methods to both smooth and also simplify paths:

http://paperjs.org/tutorials/paths/smoothing-simplifying-flattening/

Code for Simplify.js (BSD license at http://mourner.github.io/simplify-js/):

```
(function (global, undefined) {
  // to suit your point format, run search/replace for '.x' and '.y';
  // to switch to 3D, uncomment the lines in the next 2 functions
  // (configurability would draw significant performance overhead)

  function getSquareDistance(p1, p2) { // square distance between 2 points

    var dx = p1.x - p2.x,
  //        dz = p1.z - p2.z,
        dy = p1.y - p2.y;


    return dx * dx +
  //           dz * dz +
           dy * dy;
  }


  function getSquareSegmentDistance(p, p1, p2) { // square distance from a point to a segment

    var x = p1.x,
        y = p1.y,
  //        z = p1.z,


        dx = p2.x - x,
        dy = p2.y - y,
  //        dz = p2.z - z,


        t;


    if (dx !== 0 || dy !== 0) {

      t = ((p.x - x) * dx +
  //             (p.z - z) * dz +
           (p.y - y) * dy) /
              (dx * dx +
  //                 dz * dz +
               dy * dy);

      if (t > 1) {
        x = p2.x;
        y = p2.y;
  //            z = p2.z;

      } else if (t > 0) {
        x += dx * t;
        y += dy * t;
  //            z += dz * t;
      }
    }

    dx = p.x - x;
    dy = p.y - y;
  //    dz = p.z - z;

    return dx * dx +
  //           dz * dz +
           dy * dy;
  }

  // the rest of the code doesn't care for the point format

  // basic distance-based simplification

  function simplifyRadialDistance(points, sqTolerance) {

    var i,
        len = points.length,
        point,
        prevPoint = points[0],
        newPoints = [prevPoint];

    for (i = 1; i < len; i++) {
      point = points[i];

      if (getSquareDistance(point, prevPoint) > sqTolerance) {
        newPoints.push(point);
        prevPoint = point;
      }
    }

    if (prevPoint !== point) {
      newPoints.push(point);
    }

    return newPoints;
  }

  // simplification using optimized Douglas-Peucker algorithm with recursion elimination

  function simplifyDouglasPeucker(points, sqTolerance) {

    var len = points.length,

        MarkerArray = (typeof Uint8Array !== undefined + '')
                    ? Uint8Array
                    : Array,

        markers = new MarkerArray(len),

        first = 0,
        last  = len - 1,

        i,
        maxSqDist,
        sqDist,
        index,

        firstStack = [],
        lastStack  = [],

        newPoints  = [];

    markers[first] = markers[last] = 1;

    while (last) {

      maxSqDist = 0;

      for (i = first + 1; i < last; i++) {
        sqDist = getSquareSegmentDistance(points[i], points[first], points[last]);

        if (sqDist > maxSqDist) {
          index = i;
          maxSqDist = sqDist;
        }
      }

      if (maxSqDist > sqTolerance) {
        markers[index] = 1;

        firstStack.push(first);
        lastStack.push(index);

        firstStack.push(index);
        lastStack.push(last);
      }

      first = firstStack.pop();
      last = lastStack.pop();
    }

    for (i = 0; i < len; i++) {
      if (markers[i]) {
        newPoints.push(points[i]);
      }
    }

    return newPoints;
  }

  // both algorithms combined for awesome performance

  function simplify(points, tolerance, highestQuality) {

    var sqTolerance = tolerance !== undefined ? tolerance * tolerance : 1;

    points = highestQuality ? points : simplifyRadialDistance(points, sqTolerance);
    points = simplifyDouglasPeucker(points, sqTolerance);

    return points;
  };

  // export either as a Node.js module, AMD module or a global browser variable

  if (typeof exports === 'object') {
    module.exports = simplify;

  } else if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {
    define(function () {
      return simplify;
    });

  } else {
    global.simplify = simplify;
  }

}(this));
```